# Store navigation state and resume from it only while registering

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation, redux-persist

During the registration process of the app I want react-navigation to be able to resume from the component it was previously. However once the user is logged in, I no longer need to resume from where it was, I want it to start from the beginning.

I've got redux-persist for persisting my redux state and navigation state is connected correctly with react-navigation. However I am not sure if:

- I can stop persisting navigation state once a condition is met. Seems that whitelist config is hardcoded in the persistor and can't be changed.
- Is there a way to reset navigation state before StackNavigator gets it based on a condition store in the state itself.

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions#Reset

Comment: Hi maraujop, did you manage to get this working? Could really use the help. Thank you